# How can I used nested Group by in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I have 3 tables : **Invoice**, **ServicesinInvoice** and **Services** (see attached picture)

[image]

I want to create a summary report that show the daily sales for each service (cash total, debit total), I try this :

```
SELECT Service.ServiceName, SUM(ServicesinInvoice.Total) AS Total, COUNT(*) AS Count, Service.ServiceID
FROM ServicesinInvoice INNER JOIN
     Service ON ServicesinInvoice.ServiceId = Service.ServiceID INNER JOIN
     Invoice ON ServicesinInvoice.InvoiceId = Invoice.InvoiceID
WHERE (dbo.Invoice.InvoiceDate >= CONVERT(DATETIME, '2016-06-11 00:00:00', 102)) 
GROUP BY dbo.Service.ServiceName, dbo.Service.ServiceID
```

The about sql code gives me the total for each service, What I want is to get the cash total and debit total for each service (Grouped by service).

In the table (Invoice) I have **ClientId** column, If **ClientId=1** that's mean cash, else is debit.

Please help to accomplish that

Thanks in advance.

Comment: MS SQL Server Express 2012.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, that can be done with conditional aggregation :

```
SELECT Service.ServiceID,Service.ServiceName, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN Invoice.ClientId = 1 THEN ServicesinInvoice.Total ELSE 0 END) AS Total_cash,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Invoice.ClientId <> 1 THEN ServicesinInvoice.Total ELSE 0 END) AS Total_debit,
       COUNT(*) AS Count 
FROM ServicesinInvoice INNER JOIN
     Service ON ServicesinInvoice.ServiceId = Service.ServiceID INNER JOIN
     Invoice ON ServicesinInvoice.InvoiceId = Invoice.InvoiceID
WHERE (dbo.Invoice.InvoiceDate >= CONVERT(DATETIME, '2016-06-11 00:00:00', 102)) 
GROUP BY dbo.Service.ServiceName, dbo.Service.ServiceID
```

Comment: Thanks Sagi, I think that's what I want .. I will test your answer.

Comment: No problem mate @AbdulsalamElsharif

Comment: Thanks @sagi so much, I tested your answer it's exactly what I looking to do.